# NodeMCU Flashing Error

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu

My board is a NodeMCU devkit v1.0. I have been trying to flash it with a nodemcu custom build using the cloud service.(On top of standard selected ones I only add DHT library) Binary name is nodemcu-master-8-modules-2016-11-03-03-23-44-integer so I believe it uses master build 1.5.4.1

First attempt:

I used ESP8266Flasher.exe for Windows. I selected the custom build binary and flashed it to the address 0x00000.(baud:230400 Flash Speed:40 MHz SPI Mode:DIO Flash Size:4Mbyte)

At this point board was repeatedly rebooting(blue LED was going on/off at a very high frequency)

So I have gone through the documentation and learned about the problems due the change of esp_init_data_default.bin when you upgrade from a nodemcu 0.9 build.

Second attempt:

I used erase_flash using the esptool.py

```
esptool.py --port  /dev/tty.SLAB_USBtoUART erase_flash
```

and then flashed the custom build again.

Third attempt:

I did erase_flash via esptool.py. This time I downloaded the sdk patch 1.5.4.1 and flashed esp_init_data_default.bin to address 0x3fc000 with the custom build to 0x00000.

There is no rebooting error with this but when I ran ESPlorer and connect to the board I get the following message:

```
PORT OPEN 9600

Communication with MCU...
Got answer! AutoDetect firmware...
Communication with MCU established.
Can't autodetect firmware, because proper answer not received (may be unknown firmware). 
Please, reset module or continue.
```

and when I reset the module I get gibberish letters.

I tried using both dev and master branches with both integer and float binaries and I kept getting the same results.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of questions around failed flashing attempts (despite the documentation being pretty detailed). An example from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38793023/131929

It appears to me that you now have a properly flashed firmware, though.

Try setting the baud in ESPlorer to 115'200 as per https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/upload/. "Can't autodetect firmware" is an issue with ESPlorer. I learned not to depend on that.