# nodemcu uart undefined constants?

Tags: nodemcu

Using nodemcu_integer_0.9.6-dev_20150704.bin I get these strange things:

```
> uart=require("uart")
> =uart
romtable: 40240a00
>=uart.PARITY_NONE
nil
> =uart.STOPBITS_1
nil
>
```

As a result, I'm not able to do this:

```
uart.setup(0, 2400, 7, uart.PARITY_NONE, uart.STOPBITS_2, 0)
```

Just because uart.PARITY_NONE is not defined, and:

```
stdin:1: bad argument #4 to 'setup' (number expected, got nil)
```

Probably I should use a newer firmware, but the cloud build service does work for me. I just requested a new firmare and tried to flash to the device - but it does not work. When I restart the device (after flashing), the WiFi led is blinking like crazy and it sends garbage over the serial port.

Comment: Already tried to fully erase the flash by uploading an 1MB full zero file to 0x000000 0x100000 0x200000 and 0x300000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need an up-to-date firmware to use those constants (as per the [docs](http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/modules/uart/)).

As for your failed flash attempts I suggest you stick to the [documentation](http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/flash/) the cloud build service sent you a reference for. However, I suggest you build from the current `dev` branch as to avoid having to flash the new esp init data manually. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38793023/131929 for details.

Comment: The cloud build service never sent me the dev version. (I requested it many hours ago.) I was also trying to write the esp init data, but it is so confusing. Espressif says that the latest SDK version that can be used against a 4MBit flash is 1.5.4. But the readme do not specify upload addressess for 4mbit, only 8 and up.

Comment: I was wrong. The cloud build was sent to me. But for some reason, gmail marked it as spam. (But only the dev version, not the master.) I could flash the dev version to address 0x00000. Upon boot, I got the message "Formatting file system. Please wait..." I had to wait a lot. But then it works! :-)